# What is the difference between LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

In Visual Studio there are two different error numbers for the infamous unresolved symbol error in C++: [LNK2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001) and [LNK2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019). Looking at their documentation they give extensive lists of the usual and some more exotic possible causes and the general explanation at the top is identical.

So, why are there two different error numbers for the apparently same error? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a closer look I've seen that LNK2019 extends LNK2001 with `referenced in function '<function>'`.

So, I assume that Visual C++ throws LNK2019 when it can determine a function using the symbol in question and else LNK2001, while otherwise the cause of the error is the same.

In my case I've received LNK2001 for an unresolved symbol in a constructor, which is understandable because constructors are not directly callable element functions.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I was hoping for another extended answer but maybe you're right it's time to mark it.